# Python programming: input variable is returning name error

Tags: python, shell, variables, input, nameerror

So I have written this code for this game, using a user input, but it does not seem to be working. This is my code.

```
import random

print ("Welcome to the hungry dog game.")
print ("The aim of this game is to save the hungry dog. How long can you keep it alive for?")


true = True
false = False
aliveordeadlist1 = [true, false]
random.choice(aliveordeadlist1)





feed1 = input("Ok so here's your first choice. Are you going to feed your dog now or not?(he doesn't look very hungry...) type in yes or no.")
if feed1 == "no" and aliveordeadlist1 == false:
    print ("Well you were wrong, he was hungry. Your dog died sorry. Better luck next time.")

if feed1 == "yes" and aliveordeadlist1 == false:
    print ("As I told you he wansn't hungry> You overfed him so hed died sorry. Better luck next time.");
if feed1 == "no" and aliveordeadlist1 == true:
    print ("Well done he wasn't hungry. He is still alive (for now...)");
if feed1 == "yes" and aliveordeadlist1 == true:
    print ("Well done he actually was hungry so he would have died if you didn't feed him.He is still alive (for now...)");
```

When I run this code in the shell and for example, type yes, it returns this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mac/Documents/hungrydoggame.py", line 16, in <module>
    feed1 = input("Ok so here's your first choice. Are you going to feed your dog now or not?(he doesn't look very hungry...) type in yes or no.")
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'yes' is not defined
```

I am unsure why I am receiving this error and what I should do to fix it, does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Work for me just fine.

Comment: use `raw_input()`

Answer (score 1):

First of all if you're doing python2.7 program as mentioned here the [input method](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html?highlight=input#input) should be used as `input_raw` so it will return you the response as string and in line7 you do a random choice for if the dog is dead or alive but never save it in the variable in which you will be chekcing `aliveordead = random.choice(aliveordeadlist1)`. So here's the proper code.

```
import random

print ("Welcome to the hungry dog game.")
print ("The aim of this game is to save the hungry dog. How long can you keep it alive for?")


true = True
false = False
aliveordeadlist1 = [true, false]
aliveordead = random.choice(aliveordeadlist1)





feed1 = raw_input("Ok so here's your first choice. Are you going to feed your dog now or not?(he doesn't look very hungry...) type in yes or no.")

if feed1 == "no" and aliveordead == false:
    print ("Well you were wrong, he was hungry. Your dog died sorry. Better luck next time.")

if feed1 == "yes" and aliveordead == false:
    print ("As I told you he wansn't hungry> You overfed him so hed died sorry. Better luck next time.");
if feed1 == "no" and aliveordead == true:
    print ("Well done he wasn't hungry. He is still alive (for now...)");
if feed1 == "yes" and aliveordead == true:
    print ("Well done he actually was hungry so he would have died if you didn't feed him.He is still alive (for now...)");
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't get the error that you get, but you need to set the random.choice call to a variable, and then reference that in your if statements (and not `aliveordeadlist1`), otherwise you're comparing your list to the single word 'yes' or 'no' and that will always return `False`.

Answer (score 0):

This code has some serious issues which I imagine may lead to unexpected behaviour in some versions of Python:

- Indentation is relevant in Python. If you really have indented all the code after the first line I don't even understand why your code runs at all.
- You define aliases for `True` and `False`. This *may* not be a problem, but I don't know whether `true` and `false` are reserved words.

There is also a logical issue:

- You are not saving the `random.choice` return value anywhere. You are effectively checking whether `[True, False] == True` (and `== False`).

Other possible issues:

- You haven't specified which interpreter of Python you are using. `print` is a function in Python 2, but not in Python 2. I know both `assert(whatever)` and `assert whatever` work in at least some versions of Python 2, but I'm not sure about `print()`.
- Semicolons are not used to separate statements in Python, newline is.